# python разделить лист на 2, если он содержит определённое слово

Tags: python, list, split

В лист добавляются значения по типу
id(как стринг) ник.
пример:

```
"id73836" "человек"
```

нужно чтобы все id были в листе id, а ники в names
как это сделать?
edit:
изначальная запись в два листа не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id = []
names = []
for i in range(0, len(lst)-1, 2):
    id.append(lst[i])
    names.append(lst[i+1])
```

Такое лобовое решение подходит или нужно что-то более изящное и со ступид фильтрами?

Comment: со _"ступид фильтрами"_?)

Comment: ну если там список изначальный будет составлен не в виде [id,name,id,name,...] или вообще не будет содержать одного из "атрибутов". (StupidFilter)

Comment: подходит, спасибо